# Cant see my live updates on localhost from VScode

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I installed my VScode and vue.js app, but I cant see my live updates on my chrome browser.

I did 'npm install' first..
And then run 'npm run serve'
select localhost:8080 on Chrome.

Extensions downloaded: ESLint, npm Intellisense, Auto Close Tag, HTMLHint, IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML, Live HTML Previewer, Live Server,Vetur

Comment: Did you start your project from vue-cli? If yes, you don't need any vscode extension to make it work. Try disabling Live HTML previewer and Live Server.

Comment: Are there any errors reported in the terminal that's running `npm run serve`? How about in your browser's developer console?

Comment: When you say "installed" vue.js do you mean you started a new project? Simply linking to vue.js doesn't add Webpack or the Node scripts to your project. You would need to use something like [vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html) for that to happen.

Comment: Also the `serve` script will tell you the correct port to use. For example, if something else is using :8080 it will use a different port.

Comment: No error on npm run serve: C:\Users\shikh\uwf-empowers-master>npm run serve

> uwf-empowers@0.1.0 serve C:\Users\shikh\uwf-empowers-master
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
 98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 DONE  Compiled successfully in 3020ms                                                                        4:26:08 PM

  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/
  - Network: http://192.168.0.3:8080/

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.

Comment: disabling Live HTML previewer and Live Server did not work.

Comment: dev console has this..googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: That was the Ad blocker. I have removed it, but it has not helped.